# Is the order of global static variables preserved in C?

Tags: c, static

Consider :

```
  typedef struct MS{ 
   uint8_t maxlen; 
   uint8_t curlen; 
   char buf[1];  // dummy length
  } MS; 

  MS ms7;
  char ms7data[6]; /* make storage space */
  MS ms100;
  char ms100data[99]; /* make storage space */

  int main() {
      /* .... */
  }
```

The intent is that, say,  `ms7.buf` will access not only to its own char but to the following 6, equivalently as if it had been declared as `char buf[7]`. My code will initialize the `MS` fields properly and will never access the variable `ms7data`.

For this to work, I need to be sure that the compiler will respect the ordering of the (global, static) variables. Can I rely on that? (I know that is guaranteed for struct fields).

Comment: No.  You can't rely on that.  And trying to access `MS.buf[i]` with `i` larger than `1` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @CongMa : ok, but if the variables were placed inside a struct, it would be legal and the behaviour would not be undefined, right?

Comment: @CongMa  you mean `i` larger than `0` (index 0).

Comment: @leonbloy it's undefined to access out of bounds of an array, in all circumstances except for *flexible array member*. I've never seen flexible array member used in a global array but maybe it is OK

Comment: @M.M: Flexible array members are actually UB if they are accessed beyond the allocated storage, so no change here. Not sure if you can use such a struct globally anyway. You can definitively not initialize it, so how yould you define the size of the array?

Comment: @ameyCU Yes, you're right.

Comment: @Olaf yes, I'm not suggesting going beyond the allocated storage. If MS had flexible array member, then he could use `ms100data` as the storage for it, etc.  I don't see any requirement that the storage must be *dynamically* allocated.

Comment: @M.M: Well, if you think of `ms100` haing the flex array member (which is not possible) and `ms100data` to be that array, you **do access beyond the object! Any way, you have to allocate dynamically, there is no way to statically set the size of the flex array member. Relying on two variables being adjascent in memory is a clear recipe for desaster.

Comment: What you are suggesting is a clear recipe for desaster. There is also no reason to do so, even for embedded devices, there is actually no need to try. Use correct struct access. If you have to (de-)serialize data from a file/transmission link, etc. sue proper (de-)serialization functions and pack data into the struct fields by name/`offsetof`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the order is not guaranteed.  Objects may be moved around, optimized out, and so on.

In fact it is impossible for a correct program to determine which order the static variables are in (assuming there is even an ordering defined on the address space, which there may not be for segmented architecture etc).

If you want to guarantee that several global objects occur in order you must place them in a `struct`, e.g.:

```
static struct
{
    MS ms7;
    char ms7data[6]; /* make storage space */
    MS ms100;
    char ms100data[99]; 
} globals;
```

Note that there may still be padding between struct members in this scenario, but you could perhaps use compiler extensions to avoid that, or do a `sizeof` check .

Comment: Thanks. With respect with padding, I'm aware of that, but in this scenario (I don't access the dummy storage variables), I think it would not matter (`ms7.buf[1]` would be before `ms7data[0]` but who cares).

Comment: @leonbloy well, padding bytes cannot have values stored in them reliably (e.g. an optimizing compiler could re-use the padding to store temporary variables).

Comment: And you could use macros to define structures (and associated instance) on the fly.  An alternative (which you possibly know, but it's probably worth mentioning) is to dynamically assign "over-sized" blocks of memory (`MS* ms7 = malloc( sizeof(MS) + 6)`).

Comment: You can also make use of `offsetof` in `stddef.h` with your struct to verify the padding and location of members within a struct.

Comment: Yeah or you could `static_assert(sizeof globals == sizeof(MS)*2+6+99)` where `static_assert` is a macro that fails at compile-time if the argument is false

Comment: @M.M "optimizing compiler could re-use the padding to store temporary variables" oops, is that so?

Comment: For the record, I don't want to use malloc, see related: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104720/length-prefixed-strings-in-c

Comment: @leonbloy from a practical perspective it's unlikely, but my advice is to stick to what the C standard guarantees.